# Send variables to layout

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning how to build web applications using Node.js and express, so I'm really noob yet.

So, I have some questions here. I'm building a landing page, and all the informations that I'm getting from my Database (in mysql) will appear in a single page.

I'm sending values from my database, to my layout, built in Jade.

And I created multiple functions to get specific data, here an example:

```
function getUser(username, userId, callback) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?', userId, function(err, result) {
        if (err)
            callback(err, null);
        else

        var callBackString = {};
        callBackString.value1 = result[0].user_email;
        callBackString.value2 = result[0].user_name;


        callback(null, callBackString);

    });

}
```

When the user tries to login I check if the user exists to change the layout and send to the layout some important values:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    connection.query('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = ? AND user_password = ?', [req.body.login, req.body.password], function(err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;

            if (results[0]) {

                userId = results[0].user_id;

                getUser("username", userId, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("ERROR : ", err);
                    } else {

                        res.render('logged_in', {
                            email: data.value1,
                            username: data.value2,

                        });

                        res.end();

                    }

                });


            } else {
                res.render('index', {
                    validation: "failed"

                });

            }

        });

    });
```

I'm only calling one function here (getUser()), and when I call this function, the layout changes, and I send some values.

But now I would like to create a new function called getPosts(), to  get informations from a different table, and send it to the layout too, like I did when i called the function getUser()

I tried to do something like this but I had no success, when I call the variables outside the scope I keep getting "undefined".

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    connection.query('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = ? AND user_password = ?', [req.body.login, req.body.password], function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (results[0]) {

            userId = results[0].user_id;

            getUser("username", userId, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR : ", err);
                } else {
                    email = data.value1;
                    username = data.value2;

                }

            });

            getPosts("posts", 1, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR : ", err);
                } else {
                    postName = data.value1;
                    postText = data.value2;

                }

            });

            res.render('logged_in', {
                email: email,
                username: username,
                pstname: postName,
                psttxt: postText

            });

            res.end();

        } else {
            res.render('index', {
                validation: "failed"

            });

        }

    });

});
```

What do I need to change on my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about `asynchronization` in `node.js` so if you change your code as bellow it may work:

```js
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    connection.query('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = ? AND user_password = ?', [req.body.login, req.body.password], function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (results[0]) {

            userId = results[0].user_id;

            getUser("username", userId, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR : ", err);
                } else {
                    email = data.value1;
                    username = data.value2;
                  
                    getPosts("posts", 1, function(err, data) {
                      if (err) {
                          console.log("ERROR : ", err);
                      } else {
                          postName = data.value1;
                          postText = data.value2;

                        res.render('logged_in', {
                          email: email,
                          username: username,
                          pstname: postName,
                          psttxt: postText
                       }
                    });

                }

            });


        } else {
            res.render('index', {
                validation: "failed"

            });

        }

    });

});
```